# Given a circle $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, show that taking away points from the circumference gives us a disconnected space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a circle $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, how do I show that that taking away points from the circumference gives us a disconnected space?

If we take away one point, it seems to still remain connected. If more than one point is scraped off, say $a, b \in C$ such that $a \neq b$, then the parts of the two sectors that form the subsets of $C$ will likely form the two disjoint non empty open sets. But how exactly are they open? How is open-ness defined for this case? We are probably not using the Euclidean metric, although we can. Maybe we can define a metric $d(r,s)$ that considers the distance from $r$ to $s$ in the clockwise direction. But in general, how do we know that it is open for any metric we consider?

Comment: RELATIVE open, that is, a $\Bbb R^2$-open set CAP the circumpherence.

Comment: The arcs are _not_ open in the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$; none of the points on the arc has an open ball around it contained in the arc. On the other hand, they're all images of open sets of $\mathbb{R}^1$ by an injective map $\mathbb{R}^1\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki We are considering $C$ as the space. Not $\mathbb{R^2}$. Just a topological space.

Comment: We are taking circle $C$ to have the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R^2$.  You will get the two open sets in $C$ by intersecting $C$ with two open (half-planes) in $\mathbb R^2$.  That is how a subspace topology is defined.

Comment: In $C$ your two arcs are open. Prove this by using the definition. And then you're done. Because the open balls (neighborhoods) when applying the definition will be from $C$, not from $R^2$. And then it all works, the two arcs are two open disjoint subsets and that's why their union is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle minus a single point is homeomorphic to an open interval $(0,1)$ in $\Bbb R$ (or equivalently, $\Bbb R$ itself). So removing $n\ge 2$ points from the circle is the same topologically as removing $n-1$ points from $\Bbb R$, which gives us a space with $n$ components (open intervals and open segments), thus disconnected.

To see the first homeomorphism, note that e.g. $C\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)\subseteq \Bbb R$ via $t \to (\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t) \in C$ etc.